# Maintain Mac Window arrangement on Dual Screens after reconnecting monitor

Tags: macos, mac, multiple-monitors, osx-mountain-lion

I have a Mac OSX Mountain Lion setup with dual screens. After arranging the windows on both monitors, disconnecting the second monitor and reconnecting it will cause all windows to be on the first display.

Is there a way to maintain or save the window arrangement? I bring my laptop around often and find it tedious to rearrange windows when I bring the computer back to my desk where the second monitor is.

Answer (score 0):

Mac OSX does not play nice with multiple monitors. There are several options to solve this problem.

1. Use a program that keeps your windows managed. One good program I've found is [Display Maid](http://www.funk-isoft.com/index.php/display-maid)
2. Accept that your windows will become convoluted when connecting a second monitor, quickly put them back into place with [divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/)
   This is the solution that works best for me.
3. Wait until [OSX Mavericks](http://www.apple.com/osx/preview/#multiple-displays) arrives in Fall 2013. The multi monitor support has been completely rewritten, and should significantly improve OSX's multi monitor integration.

Comment: I know this is crazy out of date, and osx is 50 versions ahead, but this worked on my previous laptop (about three years old), but I just got a new one and it doesn't work anymore. I feel like I've reverted to the primitive. What happened?