# OSX window positions after unplugging & replugging external monitors

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors

I'm running two external monitors off a MacBook Pro with Mavericks. I usually have an iTerm window on each monitor and Chrome on the laptop's built-in display.

At the end of the day, I disconnect, close the laptop, and lock it away. Each morning when I plug everything in again, my windows are shuffled around: Chrome and the righthand iTerm window swap positions (and any other apps I had running seem to end up on the righthand monitor along with Chrome).

What controls this, and is there a way to make it save and restore the positioning? I use breeze for window sizing/positioning but I don't know if that affects multi-monitor stuff.

***Update:***
The simple solution was to put the mac to sleep before disconnecting, and reconnect before waking. Props to Tetsujin and his helpful comment below.

Comment: have you tried shutting down before disconnecting; & connecting before boot? If the Mac sees that external screen is gone, it's only doing its job by making sure you wouldn't lose windows off-screen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maintain Mac Window arrangement on Dual Screens after reconnecting monitor](http://superuser.com/questions/624389/maintain-mac-window-arrangement-on-dual-screens-after-reconnecting-monitor)

Comment: @Tetsujin Oh man, I'm an idiot. All it took was putting it to sleep before disconnecting, and reconnecting before waking. Everything's right where I left it.

Comment: Nice & easy, huh? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try [Display Maid](https://www.funk-isoft.com/display-maid.html). It works for the laptop configuration and then laptop + External monitors and each can have their own configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different question, but [my answer over here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/190605/131074) may explain part of your question where some of the windows are getting combined with each other on the same screen

Comment: In case our friends at ask different delete the answer, could you have the essential parts of the answer here?

Comment: Goal: keep all windows in the proper OSX “spaces” during unplug/replug.  
Solution: add 1 extra blank “space” on my laptop screen that I don’t use.


While plugged in to external monitor (a), I have space #1 on monitor and #2 & 3 on the laptop (call these 1a, 2a, 3a). #2a is kept blank.

Upon unplugging (b), there is some merging and rearranging of the Spaces happening:

1a + 2a -> 1b (This is why I left 2a blank)

3a -> 2b

End result when unplugged is my original stuff which was separated is still separated, I just don't have the extra blank display.